# How to update progress bar with different SwingWorker

Tags: java, multithreading

My application is composed of a progress bar and a status label. The progress bar should show the update of the process and the label should display a message to inform the user what process is being done.

My application will poll for a card reader that will be plugged in my pc. When the reader is detected, polling for a card presented to the reader will start. I want to execute a swingWorker for reader polling and another one for card polling. the progress bar should be updated during the polling. when there is no reader or card detected, the progress bar should pause until the the application detects a reader or card. When the card is detected, the application will access the card will do some transactions. I do'nt know how to update or compute the progress so that the progress bar will be updated properly. This is what I've done so far.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {   

        startReaderPolling();
    }

public void startReaderPolling()
    {

        try
        {           
            readerPolling = new ReaderPolling();    
            readerPolling.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
            readerPolling.execute();



        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


public class ReaderPolling extends SwingWorker<Void, String>
    {       
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception 
        {                       
            try
            {   
                AccessController.doPrivileged( new PrivilegedExceptionAction<Boolean>()
                {
                    public Boolean run()
                    {
                        while (!isCancelled())
                        {
                            try                         
                            { 
                                if(isReaderStatusChanged())
                                {
                                    if(isReaderDetected)
                                    {
                                        publish("Reader detected");
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        publish("No reader");
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                            catch(CardNotPresentException ex)
                            {

                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            catch(CardException ex)
                            {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {                               

                                ex.printStackTrace();

                            }
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                });

                return null;
            }       
            catch(PrivilegedActionException ex)
            {   
                ex.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<String> chunks)
        {
            lblStatus.setText(chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1));
        }

        @Override
        protected void done()
        {
            try {
                get();
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            lblStatus.setText("done");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Invoked when task's progress property changes.
     */
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        if ("progress" == evt.getPropertyName()) {
            int progress = (Integer) evt.getNewValue();
            ProgressBarProgress.setValue(progress);

        } 
    }
```

Comment: A `ProgressBar` displays a value that changes, such as from 0 to 100.  I don't see anything here that is "progressing" in that fashion, nor that is creating/changing your `"progress"` property.  As it stands, your question is unclear, and may likely be closed as such.

Comment: Sorry if my question is unclear. I want to update the progress bar and display the status in the following scenario:

1. reader Polling 
   Progress bar: 5% 
   status: "reader detected/removed"

2. card Polling 
   Progress bar: 15%
   status: "card presented/removed"

3. Card write/read data
   Progress bar: 20% - 100%
   status: "done"

Progress bar value are all samples only as i don't know how to compute the progress